# Where did the custom of dancing with flags during worship originate?

Tags: church-history, worship, origin, charismatic, historic-customs

I'm trying to get some background about the custom of dancing with flags during worship. I come from eastern Europe and I have seen many "trends" that came from the west (especially from charismatics). When did the churches start to dance with flags, and why?

[Here is a concrete example.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1fZif4zZVE)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Christianity, but dancing.

Comment: @Steve it's about dancing to worship Jesus Christ. Does it sound better?

Answer (score 5):

In American Christianity, specifically black or African American churches, "[praise dancing](http://www.theafricanamericanlectionary.org/PopupCulturalAid.asp?LRID=282)" is a cultural norm practiced all over the United States, generally in more progressive churches.  It is also referred to as Liturgical Dance(a).

Generally, the practice involved playing gospel ballads or other popular black gospel music from contemporary black gospel artist.  Brightly colored flags, scarves, and shawls are used and artist, usually young women, dance using ballet-like movements, in unison with the music being played as a form of worship and praise toward God.

Historically, Liturgical Dance is ancient, tracing back to even ancient Israel as noted in passages like 2 Samuel 6, albeit, this is David and many did condemn him for his expressive worship.  However, in the middle ages, according to professor Paul Dilley at the University of Iowa, the [Dance of the Savior](http://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/biblical-topics/post-biblical-period/jesus-as-lord-of-the-dance/), a liturgical dance, was probably used in some "churches and martyr shrines".  In addtion, Dilley states that a "dance scene in a Coptic text from the Qasr el-Wizz monastery suggests that ritual dance enjoyed a place in established, orthodox Christianity..."

Regardless, it is probably not possible to establish an exact reference to the beginnings of such practices in the American church.  Theologically, it is forbidden by some denominations, including some that are primarily African American, because it is consider too liberal or sensual(b).

---

(a) Based on my personal experience growing up and being involved in the Progressive Baptist Convention and other independent and other affiliated black churches primarily in and around the Washington DC Metropolitan Area.

(b) As an example of why this practice is *not* accepted, see [There is Never a Good Reason For Liturgical Dance](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/thecrescat/2013/08/there-is-never-a-good-reason-for-liturgical-dance.html)

Comment: I am wondering how the Grecian culture influence the dance as an art of worship in the young christian churches. What I mean is [Dionysian Mysteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysian_Mysteries).

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I am wrong... since I have to consider that the sister of Moses, Miriam and also even David danced before the Lord. However, personally it troubles me when I have to stand and watch these females in their latex leotards and bright colored translucent swirling and twirling scarves and capes as they go wreathing to the floor in a half or a fully prostrate position. They wave their scarves in huge twirling motions as the scarves fill the air above and around them. They prance up and down the aisles of the church twirling and swirling their scarves. Delicately and sensually if you will and at times almost seductively. Then they begin sinking to the floor folding their leotard legs beneath them... bowing their head to the floor. They might stay in that position for awhile... all the while each of the 4 to 6 females are doing different moves at different times as the "spirit" moves them. Is it an individually inspired demonstration of art? or is it indeed holy worship? or down right distraction for some of us! I find it very distracting from the move of the Holy Spirit during the altar call, or praise and worship service. I can't help but wonder what thoughts go through the minds of the men present.

It has always been my opinion and conviction that nothing should over ride or distract from the ministering of the word of God or from the worship of our Heavenly Father. To me these women are making such a *spectacle of themselves* drawing everyone's attention to them and their dance moves and colorful sensual scarves. All eyes are on them... instead of praying, praising, worshiping, heading to the altar, listening to the minister or whatever else that should be taking priority of their attention. Seems to me these girls, ladies, women... whatever are putting on their own show drawing everyone's attention on them and the rest of the congregation has been made a captive audience... captive that is unless they just get up and walk out.

If they want to dance they need to take lessons and put on their own recitals where the audience is knowingly attending to watch them perform. It is a performance. If they want to "worship" in this manner, do it at home in their prayer closet.

I personally know of young women who want to participate in this practice. I do not even believe they are born again. The fruits they are baring are not fruits of the spirit but fruits of carnality. Yet they are drawn to this activity and want to take part. They are starved for attention and want to dress up and dance around the church. Lovely, pretty but not Holy in my opinion. 
Come on people... wake up!! This is not a holy dance. I have been in Pentecost my entire life of 74 years. I come from old line Pentecost. I have seen so many non-scriptural fads come and go in the church. Some are downright disgraceful and some even demonic. Why can't we worship and function as the New Testament Churches did? Why do so many follow the leader... bark like a dog or cluck like a chicken, brae like a goat, or laugh until they cannot stand up. Laughing and appearing like idiots, staggering and falling over each other. How ridiculous... what a mockery in the house of God.

Yet in 74 years I have seen people dance a little jig if you please when the spirit comes over them. I've seen them unable to stand on their feet. I've seen people slain under the power of the Holy Spirit. I have seen people flung across the altar in a manner no human could control as demons were cast out or an anointing or pronounced over them.

I once heard a sermon about the 3 Generations of Pentecost.
First Generation... had the real thing.
Second Generation... inherited it.
Third Generation... faked it.

My God how far have we fallen. Give me the real thing or nothing at all. Praise His Holy Name!

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, 50 or more years ago many conservative and evangelical churches in the West were quite legalistic about a number of activities and behaviors they considered to be "worldly" and potentially sinful. Social dancing was one of them. Notice I say *social* dancing, not celebratory dancing or the kind of dancing you have observed in some churches (including charismatic churches), which is likely an expression of worship in which men and women, and boys and girls, do not even *touch* each other!

As many of these churches evolved, so to speak, they realized that legalism was not only unnecessarily offensive to many of the young people growing up in the church but also to the people these churches were trying to reach for Christ. Legalistic attitudes started to relax a bit. Churches started to realize that celebratory dancing as an expression of the *uninhibited worship of God* is not the same as social dancing. In other words, the two things (i.e., social dancing and celebratory dancing) are "apples and oranges"--two completely different things.

By the way, social dancing seems to have evolved, sometimes for the better and sometimes for the worse. Ballroom dancing seems to be having an upsurge in popularity. The senior pastor from my Christian church even takes ballroom dancing lessons with his wife! Among the young people in Generations X and Y, however, dancing varies from mosh pit gyrations to "dirty dancing," complete with grinding and what can be described as simulated sex acts! This "dancing" is definitely *not* in any way celebratory or worshipful. Far from it!

In many churches in the West today, and perhaps elsewhere, dancing of the kind that King David performed, as recorded in 2 Samuel, has become more common in the last decade or two:

> "David, dressed in a linen priestly vest, danced with all his strength before the LORD. 
>   This is how David and the entire house of Israel brought up the LORD's chest with shouts and trumpet blasts" (vv.14-15).

As you'll recall, Michal, Saul's daughter lost respect for David after she observed his uninhibited dance before the Lord, and she reproached him for what was in her opinion undignified behavior for a king. We read in the same chapter:

> "As the LORD's chest entered David's City, Saul's daughter Michal was watching from a window. She saw King David jumping and dancing before the LORD, and she lost all respect for him. The LORD's chest was brought in and put in its place inside the tent that David had pitched for it. Then David offered entirely burned offerings in the LORD's presence in addition to well-being sacrifices. When David finished offering the entirely burned offerings and the well-being sacrifices, he blessed the people in the name of the LORD of heavenly forces. He distributed food among all the people of Israel—to the whole crowd, male and female—each receiving a loaf of bread, a date cake, and a raisin cake. Then all the people went back to their homes. David went home to bless his household, but Saul's daughter Michal came out to meet him. "How did Israel's king honor himself today?" she said. "By exposing himself in plain view of the female servants of his subjects like any indecent person would!"  David replied to Michal, "I was celebrating before the LORD, who chose me over your father and his entire family, and who appointed me leader over the LORD's people, over Israel—and *I will celebrate before the LORD again! I may humiliate myself even more, and I may be humbled in my own eyes*, but I will be honored by the female servants you are talking about!" Michal, Saul's daughter, had no children to the day she died" (vv.16-23, italics are mine).

King David had no problem with his uninhibited worship of God. He likely would have danced naked before the Lord *if* God's Spirit had prompted him to do so!

Notice what happened to David's critic, Michal: She was unable to bear children during her lifetime. Perhaps there is a lesson in there for us. No one plays and frolics more uninhibitedly than children. Interestingly, Jesus said,

> "Assuredly, I say to you, unless you are converted and *become as little children*, you will by no means enter the kingdom of heaven" (Matthew 18:3 NLT, my italics).

In light of Michal's barrenness, we do well to rethink speaking out against the demonstrative and, yes, almost childlike behavior which has at its heart a love for and enthusiasm for our great God.

In conclusion, the relatively new phenomenon you've witnessed in Christian churches is not really new at all; it is centuries old. Uninhibited worship before the Lord, whether it includes dance of all kinds, shouts, musical instruments, banners/flags, lifted hands, drums, mime(!), and so on, is certainly biblical, and if it is done in a spirit of worship and praise, and not simply for its entertainment value, Christian churches do well to encourage the younger generations in particular to be unashamed and un-self-conscious worshipers of the Lord.

Comment: The new phenomenon is not only about dancing, generally it's about going farther in the worship, braking the walls of shame and doing things without worry about what others say. The dance is one of ways.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fascinating question that is of personal interest.

The earliest use of flags in worship that I'm aware of is in a booklet called "A Sound Of Joy" that was produced by Dave and Dale Garrett from New Zealand in 1982 I believe. Their ministry was called Scripture in Song - older people will remember it! The booklet accompanied a recording of the same name and contained dances to the songs, and some of them used flags. I have the booklet somewhere but can't find it right now. I do not know how much influence it had - I suspect not a lot. The Garretts are still around and have a website (www.davidanddalegarratt.com) so you could contact them to find out where the idea of flags came from.

Another key innovator was a guy called Andy Au who lives in England - I think he was an early adopter of flags, possibly sometime during the 1980s. He has encouraged a lot of people over the years and has travelled internationally. He can be contacted through his organisation Movement In Worship (www.miw.org.uk).

I hope this is of help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Comment: "Older people". The cheek !!!!!! :-).
If 65 is old then you are right (so I guess you are :-) ).